# English to Russian questions to be disallowed

Tags: discussion

There is no such thing as Russian-to-English at the English usage QnA. Why would we do somebody a favor?

Answer (score 3):

English.SE doesn't contain Russian-to-English questions for a simple reason: they don't have the Russian language experts to understand all the subtleties required for a correct translation. However, this site has exactly this type of experts.

If we're talking specifically about English-to-Russian questions, they should be interpreted more like the questions about how to express some certain message in Russian. This implies that you have to explain the message somehow, so you can do it in English too.

Of course, we're talking about complex cases which require some expertise. Translate-this-text-for-me questions shouldn't be allowed.

By the way, there is a good post on the similar topic on German.SE: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/152.

Comment: I disagree. You are saying that English-to-Russian questions are more welcome just because there are some people who speak English. That will lead to questions like "How do I say: 'Привет, меня зовут петя' in English" - What's the big difference? Since everybody speaks English we can do that too, can't we?

Comment: @bonomo that's already being discussed elsewhere http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8/russian-to-english-questions

Comment: It's quite different if you can read the title carefully.

Comment: @bonomo As I said in my answer, the questions must be about complex cases, requiring some expertise. What's so complex in the question you provided as an example? It's absolutely trivial.

Comment: @kotekzot This question is about English to Russian, while the one you linked is about Russian to English.

Comment: @ТимН I was referring to the comment, not the question (hence @bonomo).

Comment: I clarified my point a little, see the edit.

Comment: Malcolm, it is trivial to better illustrate the absurd of the idea of having translation allowed. Why do you think it was  supposed to be complex?

Comment: @bonomo If you ask an extremly trivial question, it only illustrates that the site is inappropriate for trivial questions. It doesn't show anything, you can provide the same kind of questions for any topic.

Comment: Malcolm, you are drifting away, let me summarize my points just for you, 2 simple statements: 1) There should be no favorable language, but Russian. Consequently English or anything else has nothing to do with being more welcomed. 2) However a question in any language must have equal chances to be heard/answered as long as the community can read it and the question represents a problem of using Russian. So the language of question is just a tool to communicate a problem, but not the part of the problem itself.

Comment: @bonomo Your second point hits the spot. Now ask yourself a question, what language except Russian you would use to enable more people to understand the question, especially considering that the SE network uses English?

Comment: Malcolm, this is a language SE which specializes in Russian by design and the whole original idea. People who don't understand Russian well enough will get their question answered in their mother language at the best of this community, but before this happens those people need to manage to get here and have some courage to speak. By which I am saying there are no random folks. Pretty much everyone in here knows Russian more or less. But.. This doesn't mean we should accept problems out of the original purpose domain. Like how to say a Russian sentence in the language of ladybugs.

Comment: @bonomo How do the requirements for the language in which questions are asked relate to the specific types of questions of conveying a certain message in Russian? You may as well propose to ban English from the site altogether, only I really doubt that many will second that. As for the people using their native languages, it should be obvious that this will seriuosly limit usefulness of the questions for the other people, and also decrease the number of experts who can answer the question.

Comment: @Malcom, I am sorry you don't seem being interested in hearing what I am saying: YOU: "How do the requirements for the language in which questions are asked relate to the specific types of questions of conveying a certain message in Russian?" ME: These 2 relate in no way to each other. Why would you mention that? YOU: "You may as well propose to ban English from the site altogether." ME: Again, as I said "will get their question answered in their mother language at the best of this community". Why would you mention that?

Comment: @Malcom, 1) Use any language you want as long as the question relates to a problem of the Russian language. Everybody is welcome! English speaking people at the first place. 2) Problems of translation from Russian to the language of fish and back is not solely a Russian language problem and should not be permitted. 3) Period

Comment: @bonomo Because my answer was only about the reasons for allowing English questions about conveying certain messages in Russian. Comments are intended to seek clarification for the answer. If you want to talk about anything else, you should open a new question or move the discussion to the chat.